# GCM APN messages aren't delivered

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to send messages to a device using **GCM**. I'm sending this JSON to the client:

```
  {
"to": "nzgmI.....smZq9tE_L6k4C6T",
"data": {
  "message": "vale normal de menfdasfdsajes",
 }
}
```

And I can see it on the console, but if I want to have a standard ios push notification to get a dialog I didn't receive anything.

```
  {
    "to": "nzgmIZ764.....tE_L6k4C6T",
    "notification" : {
      "body" : "I can't see this",
      "title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark",
      "icon" : "myicon"
    }
  }
```

I have a print in:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
```

But only with the first option I can actually see something in the console, and I want to achieve a regular push notification not just a message.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to add the `priority` field to your message i.e.

```
{
    "to": "nzgmIZ764.....tE_L6k4C6T",
    "priority" : "high", // Add this 
    "notification" : {
      "body" : "I can't see this",
      "title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark",
      "icon" : "myicon"
    }
}
```

If you receive a `Successful` response from GCM you should see a normal notification being delivered to your app.